# change host name to 0.0.0.0 in ktor

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, host, ktor

I want to change host in ktor in a EngineMain project. by default ktor uses 127.0.0.1 host in HOCON file but I want to change it to 0.0.0.0. the problem is when I add host attribute in deployment tag in HOCON file and change it to 0.0.0.0, it's still using the default host (127.0.0.1). I tried other hosts and ktor use them correctly but when I change it to 0.0.0.0 it uses the default host.

how can I fix it?

[HOCON file (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye7zN.png)

**UPDATE**
I realized that my code has no problem I tested my code on another computer and it hosted on 0.0.0.0 but I still have trouble with it I don't know what is hosting me on 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution will it work for you give it a try

```
embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            gson {
                setPrettyPrinting()
            }
        }

        routing {
            get("/") {
                call.respondText("Hello, World!", contentType = ContentType.Text.Plain)
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
```

Comment: I want a solution on EnginMain do you have any idea?